# Django - Always shows 'It Worked!' page

Tags: django

So I just setup django and this is the first time I'm getting a problem like this, I'm completely mystified.

I'm simply always getting the 'It Worked' introductory page. No matter what I put after the URL, I'm just getting that page. Even if I put an invalid string after 127.0.0.1:8000, such as 127.0.0.1/asda231da, I still get the 'it worked' page instead of the URL not found debug page.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from mainapp.views import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^app/$', app),



    )
```

Funny part is, the 'app' view I'm referring to doesn't even exist, still Django doesn't throw any error.

What could be going on?

Comment: How are you sure the Django site is being accessed?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server? Do you have `myapp` inside `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?